# Replacing multiple words in a text file and writing new text to output file

Tags: python, loops, replace, output

I am trying to write a function which takes a text file as input file and create an output file with the same text with words replaced. This function will edit Emma with George, she with he and her with his.

My code is:

```
switch = {"Emma":"George", "she":"he", "hers":"his"}

def editWords(fin):
    #open the file
    fin = open(filename, "r")
    #create output file
    with open("Edited.txt", "w") as fout:
        #loop through file
        for line in fin.readlines():
            for word in switch.keys():
                if word in line.split():
                    line = line.replace(word, switch[word])
                fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
```

The out put file is created however blank.

Does anyone know how to get the output file with the edited text?

Comment: Where are you writing to the file? you are not using the `.write` mothod .  also see this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: I don't see where you ever invoke `fout.write(edited)`. Unless you write something into the file, it expectedly remains blank.

Comment: you also have a `if i in switch:` statement inside of a `for i in switch:` loop. `i` will always then be in `switch`...?

Comment: I edited the code. I had the if i in switch statement inside the for loop because I previously got an error global name i is not defined. I am back to that point and not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

- You never write the file.
- You use i in two loops
- You never close the infile
- You don't respect the newlines
- ...

Here an example that works

```
switch = {"Emma":"George", "she":"he", "hers":"his"}

def editWords(filename):
    #open the file
    fin = open(filename, "r")
    #create output file
    with open("/tmp/Edited", "w") as fout:
        #loop through file
        for line in fin.readlines():
            for word in switch.keys():
                if word in line.split():
                    line = line.replace(word, switch[word])
            fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
editWords("/tmp/filename")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to programming and appreciate the help.

I have text in my output file, however only the first Emma is switched with George, the rest remains the same.

Comment: I pasted the code I am running which is slightly different than yours because I need to take the file name from user input.

The output is still off.

Is it because of my slight alterations?

Comment: The problems are the function argument: `filename` not `fin` and the write indentation. (I edit my post)